# Loop trouble in c? what is wrong here?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, char

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char c='y';
    int n=0;
    while(c=='y')
        {
            printf("this is loop number %d\n", n);
            n++;
            printf("do you wish to continue? (y/n)");
            c=getchar();
        }
       return 0; 
    }
```

The while loop is exiting after the initial iteration and the getchar is not taking the character input as expcted! what's wrong with the implementation here.

Comment: use `getche()` instead of `getchar()`

Comment: So what is it doing?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Don't use `scanf` for user input.

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi What's `getche`?

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi You never want `scanf`.

Comment: I'm implementing in turbo c and the getchar is not taking any input at all! and the loop is terminating on its own after executing till the last printf statement.

Comment: @DivyanshuSrivastava Interesting. What's in `c` at the end?

Comment: @melpomene `getche` is a function that reads a character from user and shows it on the terminal , like `getch` function but `getch` reads character from user and doesn't show it to user

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi `getche` is obviously non-standard and should not be used

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi Neither of those are standard C, and they don't exist on my system.

Comment: @melpomene you must `#include <conio.h>`

Comment: @artm `#include <conio.h>`

Comment: well the 'getche' worked but I have never used that before! strange.

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi We all know what `<conio.h>` is, but that's Microsoft specific and won't work on another platform because it's not standardised

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi File not found.

Comment: what is your platform @melpomene ?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi Arch Linux.

Comment: @melpomene yeah , it doesn't work on linux , i didn't advice that , i just wanna say that this works , just in this case

Comment: I think the issue is new line or some sorta white space being left in the buffer which is being directly read into c char instead of asking user for the input! Because using 'scanf' with a space before '%c' is also working fine, But without that space it's skipping input and terminating!

Comment: After `c=getchar();` add a debug line of `printf("%d\n", c);` to illuminate what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

When the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, two characters are generated: `'y'` or `'n'` *and* a newline character `'\n'`. The first call to `getchar()` gets the letter, the next call gets the newline. Your code must ignore all newlines.

```
do { c = getchar(); } while(c == '\n');
```

Comment: @Stargateur To eliminate all newlines, as many of them may be in the keyboard buffer.

Comment: I understand this but why use a `do; while;` loop instead of a `while;` loop? It's just a question not a critic. You have an issue if `getchar()` return `EOF`. You should change your answer to fix this issue.

Comment: @Stargateur You must get `c` first and only then decide whether to keep it or not. With `while`, you must check the condition before executing the action. As for `EOF`, `getchar()` returns it only at the end of file, which happens only when the program is terminated by ^C or ^D, or at keyboard error.

Comment: `getchar()` is standard ?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi Yes it is: _CONFORMING TO C89, C99, POSIX.1-2001._

Comment: i didn't know that , when i was learning these functions , i've learned four functions , `gets()` , `getch()` , `getche()` and `getchar()` , i didn't know `getche()` is not standard , what about `gets()` function ?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi Why don't you read manual pages for all these functions? They clearly mark standard functions and extensions.

Comment: @DYZ why are you going to be angry ... relax buddy , relax :)) ok , i'll do it

Answer (score 0):

When you type "y" with enter on your terminal, you have entered two characters. `'y'` and `'\n'` so `getchar()` return '\n' on the second call. Plus `getchar()` return a `int` not a `char` but you stock it in `char c`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int c = 'y';
  int n = 0;
  while (c == 'y') {
    printf("this is loop number %d\n", n);
    n++;
    printf("do you wish to continue? (y/n)");
    while ((c = getchar()) == '\n' && c != EOF);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You can use `scanf()` because `getchar()` is very limited.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {
  int n = 0;
  while (true) {
    printf("this is loop number %d\n", n++);
    printf("do you wish to continue? (y/n)\n");
    char c;
    if (scanf(" %c", &c) != 1 || c != 'y') {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Or:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  int n = 0;
  {
    char c;
    do {
      printf("this is loop number %d\n", n++);
      printf("do you wish to continue? (y/n)\n");
    } while (scanf(" %c", &c) == 1 && c == 'y');
  }
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Why? Do you prefer `" %c"`?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You are wrong https://ideone.com/Qnra1G. Or explain yourself more clearly because you don't help here i will report your comment like spam. If you want troll someone don't choice me because I will win. It's not because you have a lot of reputation that you can be unpleasant.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY After try to fix it, I think "this is not an issue...". So I don't care. The OP never ask that `'\n'` must stop the loop and the first answer has the same behavior.

Comment: A trouble with `(scanf("%c\n", &c)` is that on its first call and the user types `<x>`, `<Enter>` , the function does not return right away.  The `'\n'` tells `scanf()` to consume all white space until some non-white space is found.  With buffered input, that means another line of input like `<y>`, `<Enter>`  `scanf()` sees the `y`, puts it back into `stdin` and returns 1 with `x` in `c`.  So the user had to type 2 lines of input to read one character on the first call.

Comment: @chux Indeed, this is logic. Thank, I never use `scanf()`, I prefer use my own parser. But I try to understand `scanf()`, I always miss something. This function is very complex. So, " %c" should do the trick.

Comment: @Stargateur  `scanf()` does not handle the combination of reading, parsing and nature of user input - both nefarious and error-prone.  Simplest to read a line, like with `fgets()` and then parse it as needed.  Unfortunately, too much early learning is spent with reading/parsing `scanf()` with its foibles.

Comment: @Stargateur `\n` in scanf format string does not do what you think it does, please read the manual.  The ideone example does not illustrate the problem because ideone does not have interactive input